# Hats are coming off from profile picture

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, winter-bash

I am seeing a post and someone suddenly edited it and his hat come off and after some time entire picture is gone.

[image]

Link to the question: [How to return every kth element of output file in input file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354039/how-to-return-every-kth-element-of-output-file-in-input-file)

Comment: Been reported many times in various different situations.  It's a bit of a quirk that we're living with right now.